# Fonts not showing up in InfoPath Designer 2010

Tags: infopath

I have downloaded and installed font FF Meta. The Font names shows up in Ms-Word and OneNote but it doesn't list in Infopath Designer 2010.

Font shows up in OneNote.

[image: Font lists in OneNote]

font doesn't show in infopath designer 2010.

[image]

Comment: try installing different fonts and see if they show up in the list. are any other custom fonts showing?

Comment: If I copy and paste the font to infopath and If I move the cursor over the text then the font name shows in names list.

Comment: Is it .otf or .ttf font type? seems tool doesn't list .otf type fonts.